# D3 js update plot just adds new points on top

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph that has data updating every second. The limits do not change and all I want to do is clear the graph and put the new points onto it. But currently this just adds all of the points on top of the last ones.

```
 main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(yAxis); 

  g = main.append("svg:g");

function update(data){
  g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
    .data(data)  
    .enter().append("svg:circle")  // create a new circle for each value
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d); } ) // translate y value to a pixel
        .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(xdata[i]); } ) // translate x value
        .attr("r", 4); // radius of circle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to add an `exit()` call to tell `d3` to remove any points from the graph that are no longer in the dataset. Generally you will also want to use an enter (for new elements), update (for existing elements), and exit (for removed elements) strategy when working with `d3`.  The pattern usually looks like this:

```
function update(data){
  var points = g.selectAll("scatter-dots").data(data);

  points.enter().append("svg:circle");  // create a new circle for each value

  points  
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d); } ) // translate y value to a pixel
    .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(xdata[i]); } ) // translate x value
    .attr("r", 4); // radius of circle

  points.exit().remove();
}
```